# How do I run a process then get notified when it has exited?

Tags: c++, winapi, process

I'm trying to reimplement .NET's [`Process.Exited`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx) Event but I've been unsuccessfully so far. No error is returned by the application doesn't open. What am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

static void CALLBACK OnExited(void* context, BOOLEAN isTimeOut);

int main() 
{
    char *cmd = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe";
    STARTUPINFOA si = { sizeof(STARTUPINFOA) };
    //si.cb = STARTUPINFOA.sizeof;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    if(CreateProcessA(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, FALSE, DETACHED_PROCESS | CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        HANDLE hWait;
        if(!RegisterWaitForSingleObject(&hWait, pi.hProcess, OnExited, NULL, INFINITE, WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE))
        {
            printf("register failed! = %d", GetLastError());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("error = %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
}

static void CALLBACK OnExited(void* context, BOOLEAN isTimeOut)
{
    printf("OnExited got called!\n");
}
```

Comment: @Robinson: it is not a duplicate. The `Process.Exited` event is notified when a new process is spawned by the app's own code via `Process.Start()` and is then waited on asynchronously. The linked question is about how to detect the creation/termination of external processes that the app did not spawn itself.

Comment: Whoa. This was voted as off-topic? This is not programming? I'm really confused right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating the new process with the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag, but you are not resuming the process (by passing `pi.hThread` to `ResumeThread()`) after registering the new process `HANDLE` for notification.  Even if you did, you are not waiting for the notification to arrive before exiting from `main()`.

You are also not closing `pi.hThread`, `pi.hProcess`, or `hWait` after you are done using them.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

static void CALLBACK OnExited(void* context, BOOLEAN isTimeOut);

int main() 
{
    char *cmd = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe";

    STARTUPINFOA si = {};
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    if (!CreateProcessA(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, FALSE, DETACHED_PROCESS | CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        printf("create process error = %u\n", GetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        HANDLE hWait = NULL;

        HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
        if (!hEvent)
        {
            printf("create event error = %u\n", GetLastError());
        }
        else if (!RegisterWaitForSingleObject(&hWait, pi.hProcess, OnExited, hEvent, INFINITE, WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE))
        {
            printf("register wait error = %u\n", GetLastError());
        }

        ResumeThread(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

        if (hEvent)
        {
            if (hWait)
            {
                WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
                UnregisterWait(hWait);
            }

            CloseHandle(hEvent);
        }

        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    }

    return 0;
}

static void CALLBACK OnExited(void* context, BOOLEAN isTimeOut)
{
    printf("OnExited got called!\n");
    SetEvent((HANDLE)context);
}
```

Or, if you omit the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag, you can then omit the `ResumeThread()`. The wait notification will still work even if the process ends before the wait thread begins monitoring it, as long as you don't close the process handle before the wait is satisfied:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

static void CALLBACK OnExited(void* context, BOOLEAN isTimeOut);

int main() 
{
    char *cmd = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe";

    STARTUPINFOA si = {};
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    if (!CreateProcessA(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, FALSE, DETACHED_PROCESS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        printf("create process error = %u\n", GetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

        HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
        if (!hEvent)
        {
            printf("create event error = %u\n", GetLastError());
        }
        else
        {
            HANDLE hWait = NULL;
            if (!RegisterWaitForSingleObject(&hWait, pi.hProcess, OnExited, hEvent, INFINITE, WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE))
            {
                printf("register wait error = %u\n", GetLastError());
            }
            else
            {
                WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
                UnregisterWait(hWait);
            }

            CloseHandle(hEvent);
        }

        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    }

    return 0;
}

static void CALLBACK OnExited(void* context, BOOLEAN isTimeOut)
{
    printf("OnExited got called!\n");
    SetEvent((HANDLE)context);
}
```

However, either way, using `RegisterWaitForSingleObject()` isn't very beneficial in such a simple console app.  It makes more sense in a multithreaded/GUI app instead.  For this example, you could just use `WaitForSingleObject()` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() 
{
    char *cmd = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe";

    STARTUPINFOA si = {};
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOA);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    if (!CreateProcessA(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, FALSE, DETACHED_PROCESS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        printf("create process error = %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        printf("Exited!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a console application but in my real code I'll run up to run 4 applications at time in parallel and run a new one soon as one is exited, until the list is finished. I'm trying to implemente this.

Answer (score -1):

I think the basic problem here is your main process is terminating, i.e. if you do something like:

```
#include <thread>

std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10000));
```

on your main thread, the handler will be called.  In your example/demo your program has nothing else to do.

I mean apart from CREATE_SUSPENDED, which obviously does what it says so you'll never see your created process's window.

This works for me:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

static void CALLBACK OnExited(void* context, BOOLEAN isTimeOut);

int main()
{   
    char *cmd = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe";

    STARTUPINFOA si = { sizeof(STARTUPINFOA) }; 
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    if (CreateProcessA(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, FALSE, DETACHED_PROCESS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        HANDLE hWait;

        if (!RegisterWaitForSingleObject(&hWait, pi.hProcess, OnExited, NULL, INFINITE, WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE))
        {
            std::cout << "register failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "error creating process: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    // Engage in shenanigans otherwise we'll just exit main.

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10000));
}

static void CALLBACK OnExited(void* context, BOOLEAN isTimeOut)
{
    std::cout << "OnExited got called!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: you not close `pi.hProcess` and `pi.hThread`. you not call `UnregisterWait` - so you have resource leaks

Comment: No, I don't.  I'm making the OP's code "work", i.e. the problem is the process is terminating.

Comment: but code is wrong anyway - not free resources serious error

Comment: It's not "leaking" is it.  Any resources allocated by the process are freed on process termination.  It may be bad practice but that is a different issue.

Answer (score -4):

you can use for example next code:

```
class __declspec(novtable) _WAIT_CTX 
{
    HANDLE hObject, WaitHandle;

    static VOID CALLBACK _WaitOrTimerCallback(PVOID lpParameter, BOOLEAN /*TimerOrWaitFired*/)
    {
        reinterpret_cast<_WAIT_CTX*>(lpParameter)->_OnWaitCallback();
    }

    void _OnWaitCallback()
    {
        OnWaitCallback(hObject);
        delete this;
    }
protected:
    virtual ~_WAIT_CTX()
    {
        if (WaitHandle) UnregisterWait(WaitHandle);
        if (hObject) CloseHandle(hObject);
    }
    virtual void OnWaitCallback(HANDLE hObject) = 0;
public:

    ULONG Register(HANDLE h)
    {
        hObject = h;

        if (RegisterWaitForSingleObject(&WaitHandle, h, 
            _WaitOrTimerCallback, this, INFINITE, WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE))
        {
            return NOERROR;
        }

        ULONG dwError = GetLastError();

        delete this;

        return dwError;
    }

    _WAIT_CTX() : hObject(0), WaitHandle(0)
    {
    }
};

class WAIT_CTX : public _WAIT_CTX
{
    virtual void OnWaitCallback(HANDLE hProcess)
    {
        ULONG exitCode;
        GetExitCodeProcess(hProcess, &exitCode);
        DbgPrint("exitcode=%x", exitCode);
    }
};

ULONG bbb()
{
    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ULONG dwError;
    if (CreateProcessW(L"c:\\windows\\notepad.exe", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

        if (WAIT_CTX* p = new WAIT_CTX)
        {
            dwError = p->Register(pi.hProcess);
        }
        else
        {
            dwError = ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY;
            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
    }

    return dwError;
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty but something about "delete this" is giving off an awful smell.

Comment: @Robinson - this (`delete this`) is absolute correct here and must be. if want can move this line to `_WaitOrTimerCallback` - `delete reinterpret_cast<WAIT_CTX*>(lpParameter)`; but this is nothing changed by sense

Comment: Your class does nothing to guarantee it was created on the heap.  But what do I know...

Comment: @Robinson - my class created by `new` ( `WAIT_CTX* p = new WAIT_CTX(pi.hProcess)`) and deleted by coresponded `delete`

Comment: @Robinson - i not understand what you mean or want. my code absolute correct - in what your problem ?

Comment: @Robinson - my code is absolute correct. and at this line where i call this - this is correct. if you have bad knowledge - this is your problem only. you can not even explain yourself why this you mean that this (`delete this`) is error

Comment: The problem is you allow a user to `WAIT_CTX doomed;` You should wall this off with `private` constructors and a `static` member factory function that forces dynamic allocation. Five bucks says this is what @Robinson 's posted link is suggesting.

Comment: @user4581301 - i not write here release library class code. i show very basic example of usage `RegisterWaitForSingleObject`. concrete posted code is absolute correct. handle all possible errors and free all resources. i not care here about wrong usage of class. of course possible make destructor private four you be happy :)

Comment: No worries. Just explaining what Robinson was likely worried about and leaving a breadcrumb for those who follow.

Comment: @user4581301 - i really not understand *c++* adepts . frequently they absolute not worried about resource leaks at all. not handle errors. but than that aesthetically dissatisfied in absolute correct code which handle all errors and free all resources. if very want - here more *c++* version - but again - i here not write class library - this is example of winapi usage of notify

Comment: For someone who [correctly] commented _"not free resources serious error"_ on another answer, this is quite the fun submission  `delete this`? Just no. Is it valid? Sure, in this case. Is it a good idea? **NO.** Please do not forget that you are teaching.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - and so what ? you mean my pure english or something else ? i give the general example of correct usage `RegisterWaitForSingleObject`. how correct call it and not forget free all handles. i not show here master class of *c++* - this question not about this. fanny if i coding here in *c* style - pure struct without member functions - will be no problems ? or i simply not use context and not free handles (as robinson) this will be ok ? :)

Comment: No idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - i too have no idea about you talking

Comment: Then I will repeat one more time: `delete this` Is it a good idea? NO.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - this is **correct** code. this all what i can say. and i not view any bad here

Comment: Correct, yes. Good, no.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - and what it is not "good" ? i understand what i doing and can do this. somebody not like my style ? and so what. much more bad for me write code which not free resources and not handle errors. and i here not write application. may be use `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` not good idea here at all. but i show in general how this winapi/notification used. this is by sense winapi question but not about good c++ style. especially if compare my answer with another. not view that it more bad. faster otherwise

Comment: @RbMm: Read the FAQ entry you were linked to.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - faster read OP question - about what it. can also read another answer (say Robinson) and compare with my. about faq - i have enough knowledge and i free do what i want do

Comment: Furthermore, this post does not explain the OP's problem nor does it explain the solution provided.

Comment: And since no one noted (which you will certainly call off as aesthetics): `_WaitOrTimerCallback` is a [reserved symbol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers). This code isn't even valid.

Comment: Not a big fan of clicking hyperlinks, eh? The link explains, that your code exhibits undefined behavior. Appearing to work is a valid form of undefined behavior. It's still undefined.

Comment: @IInspectable - this is not UB. this is only theoretical reserved symbol. until it by fact not. if even it will be used in future for something else - compiler  simply give error for this usage

Comment: Right from the [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) I posted two comments above: *"If the programmer uses such [reserved] identifiers, the behavior is undefined."* What sources do you have, that this were not undefined behavior? Then again, it's the old issue revisited: You do not understand contracts. I would greatly appreciate it, if you informed yourself before commenting back.

Comment: @IInspectable - the **compiler** behavior is undefined - in sense compiler say can compile this without errors or refuse compile, because it used this symbol

Comment: That is your interpretation. And that interpretation does not coincide with reality. Again, please do inform yourself, and do not comment on contracts, until you understand contracts.

Comment: @IInspectable - no, this not only my interpretation. this is fact. i unlike you can think yourself

Comment: Er, unlike me, you can think myself? I'm going to side with @Lightness here, and call this a fun submission.

Comment: @IInspectable - i view already how you can think yourself. only documentation and all

Comment: Good spot on the reserved word @IInspectable. I'd missed that. Yes, this code example has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - what you want really ? the code which i posted here the best from existing. i free all resources and not do senseless wait in place, which kill sense of asynchronous callback. no any errors in code . you are *c++* ultra adept ? and so what ? my code is absolute correct and efficient

Comment: It is not the best. It has undefined behaviour. It is the worst. If you spent less time arguing with people you may stand to learn something; unfortunately, you have no interest in that, so we can only delete this answer to protect other readers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - maximum what can be - some compiler can refuse compile this code and say that symbol wrong used. nothing more. you and yourself understand this. and question was not about c++ formal standard and documentation. really - what you want ? code the best from winapi (windows) view